# Trying to add reference to project in Visual Studio 2012, "no items found"

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to add a reference to `System.dll` and `System.drawing.dll` to my project in Visual Studio 2012. I'm doing this by right clicking the project, clicking "references", and then clicking "Add new reference".

It seems like the following screen should have a lot of options, but for me it simply says "No Items Found". In the screen it says my targeted framework is `.NETFramework, Version=v4.0`.

Is there anything else I need to be doing in order to make the options show up?

Comment: Do you have enabled the /CLR support in your project? (`Properties|General||Common Language Runtime Support: /CLR`)

Comment: I didn't, but that's sorted it. Thanks a lot, put that as an answer and I'll select it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable CLR support in your application. You can do that in the properties of your project: `Properties|General||Common Language Runtime Support: Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)`

Comment: Works for VS2015, as well.