# Unable to add references to ASP.NET Core 1.1 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I looked at [Trying to add reference to project in visual studio 2012 no items found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672025/trying-to-add-reference-to-project-in-visual-studio-2012-no-items-found) and this appears to be dead on with what I'm experiencing except I'm using Visual Studio 2017. Except I don't see anything General/CLR related in properties (I think that is because the initial question is in reference to a desktop application of some sort).

I'm attempting to add System.Net.Mail, but Dependencies -> Add References for Projects, Projects - Solution, Shared Projects, Shared Projects - Solution, Browse, and Browse Recent are show "No items found."

If I click the parents (Projects/Shared Projects/Browse) or their lone children, this is what I see:

[image: What the popup shows.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Net.Mail` is included in the dotnet core 2.0 SDK. If you look its already referenced. However, according to [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/12416#issuecomment-330279488) System.Net.Mail is more compact in core, and if you want something with a lot more features you should consider mailkit, or other packages.

Comment: strange, I'm looking at MailMessage, SmtpClient (different dll I believe), and MailAddress and when right clicking to add reference, it only gave me options to generate those classes. Only HttpClient and NetworkCredential were able to be located directly (System.Net, System.Net.Http). It just seems odd as when I've previously done .NET, I could add either framework items like this or there was one for other explicit DLLs. Now, it just says "No items found" across the board.

Comment: right clicking to use the Quick Actions and Refactorings, sorry, not sure why I said add reference

Comment: Apparently the question was updated to mention .NET Core 1.1 after you posted this answer.

Comment: It was, sorry, updated one part while working on something else and didn't comment. It is from 1.1. I tried updating to 2 and it butchered the application so I had to recreate a 1.1 app and then drop in everything back to it (trying to use nuget to drop versions irrecoverably broke it)

Comment: 'Referenced' DLL's in the framework use the Global Assembly Cache, a construct that does not exist in core. That is why the dialog is empty.

Comment: System.Net.Mail was not in 1.1, its 2.0 minimum IIRC

Comment: You're right. It appears it didn't come until 2.0 and the options are re-attempt to upgrade to 2.0 (last time I attempted, there were some issues that required restarting because it wasn't version controlled at the time) or use a library called MailKit which appears to be fairly similar if not the same in API: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/11/sending-receiving-email-net-core/